# Apache Ignite client failed to connect with Ignite Server(On Different VM's)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

Ignite Version is 2.9.0 for Both Ignite Server(Docker Image already running on different VM) and Java Spring Boot client (which I am trying to run on Different VM)

This is my ConfigurationFactory.java for Client

```
public class ConfigurationFactory {

  private ConfigurationFactory() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Configuration Factory Class");
  }

  public static IgniteConfiguration createConfiguration() {

    TcpCommunicationSpi tcpCommunicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    tcpCommunicationSpi.setLocalPort(10801);

    TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
    ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("192.168.10.161:47500"));
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    // Setting some custom name for the node.
    cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("myService");
    // Enabling peer-class loading feature.
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
    // Override default communication SPI.
    cfg.setCommunicationSpi(tcpCommunicationSpi);

    DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();

    DataRegionConfiguration dataRegionCfg = new DataRegionConfiguration();

    dataRegionCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    dataStorageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(dataRegionCfg);

    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageCfg);

    // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data
    // repository.
    CacheConfiguration ccfgClient = new CacheConfiguration(Constant.CLIENT_IGNITE_CACHE_NAME);

    // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
    ccfgClient.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Client.class);

    ccfgClient.setAtomicityMode(TRANSACTIONAL);

    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfgClient);

    return cfg;
  }

}
```

And this is my SpringDataConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableIgniteRepositories
public class SpringDataConfig {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger(Components.class);

  @Bean
  public Ignite igniteInstance() {

    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = ConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration();
    igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);
    igniteConfiguration.setFailureDetectionTimeout(50000);
    igniteConfiguration.setNetworkTimeout(50000);
    igniteConfiguration.setSystemWorkerBlockedTimeout(50000);
    igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);
    LOGGER.info("Ignite Started!!!!!!!!!!!");
    ignite.cluster().active(true);
    return ignite;
  }
}
```

After running Java Spring boot based Client I am getting this result on console.
I am able to create Cache Table successfully but connection break after that.

```
[10:38:30]    __________  ________________ 
[10:38:30]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[10:38:30]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[10:38:30] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[10:38:30] 
[10:38:30] ver. 2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8
[10:38:30] 2020 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[10:38:30] 
[10:38:30] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[10:38:30] 
[10:38:30] Quiet mode.
[10:38:30]   ^-- Logging to file 'C:\Users\user\Company-Projects\Ignitehome\apache-ignite-2.7.6-src\work\log\ignite-9397d621.0.log'
[10:38:30]   ^-- Logging by 'JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
[10:38:30]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[10:38:30] 
[10:38:30] OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
[10:38:30] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.6+10 AdoptOpenJDK OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.6+10
[10:38:30] Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
[10:38:30] Initial heap size is 510MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[10:38:30] Configured plugins:
[10:38:30]   ^-- None
[10:38:30] 
[10:38:30] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[10:38:30] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[10:38:30] Security status [authentication=off, sandbox=off, tls/ssl=off]
[10:38:31] REST protocols do not start on client node. To start the protocols on client node set '-DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true' system property.
[10:38:43] Data Regions Started: 3
[10:38:43]     ^--   sysMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=false,
[10:38:43]       ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=0MB, allocTotal=0MB]
[10:38:43]     ^--   default region [type=default, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=true,
[10:38:43]       ...  initCfg=256MB, maxCfg=6512MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=0MB, allocTotal=0MB]
[10:38:43]     ^--   TxLog region [type=internal, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=false,
[10:38:43]       ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=0MB, allocTotal=0MB]
[10:38:43]     ^-- Ignite persistence [used=0MB]
[10:38:44] Topology snapshot [ver=681, locNode=9397d621, servers=1, clients=2, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=14, offheap=16.0GB, heap=16.0GB]
[10:38:44]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
[10:38:58,024][SEVERE][grid-timeout-worker-#22%organization-service%][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=partition-exchanger, threadName=exchange-worker-#42%organization-service%, blockedFor=14s]
[10:38:58] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=organization-service, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1603777123241]]]
[10:39:01,041][SEVERE][grid-timeout-worker-#22%organization-service%][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=disco-event-worker, threadName=disco-event-worker-#41%organization-service%, blockedFor=16s]
[10:39:01] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=disco-event-worker, igniteInstanceName=organization-service, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1603777124562]]]
[10:39:03,255][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#42%organization-service%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, consistentId=117403a3-0118-446e-a134-55d21c5342af, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.23.0.2], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /172.23.0.2:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1603777111439, loc=false, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_METADATA_REQ, topicOrd=25, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=MetadataRequestMessage [typeId=4]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3935)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3635)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3375)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3180)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3013)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2960)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2100)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.ClientMetadataRequestFuture.requestMetadata(ClientMetadataRequestFuture.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.BinaryMetadataTransport.requestUpToDateMetadata(BinaryMetadataTransport.java:371)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.metadata0(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:733)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl$1.metadata0(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.affinityKeyFieldName(BinaryContext.java:1238)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.affinityKeyField(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:1061)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheDefaultBinaryAffinityKeyMapper.affinityKeyField(CacheDefaultBinaryAffinityKeyMapper.java:133)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheDefaultBinaryAffinityKeyMapper.affinityKeyField(CacheDefaultBinaryAffinityKeyMapper.java:101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.QueryUtils.typeForQueryEntity(QueryUtils.java:521)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.createQueryCandidates(GridQueryProcessor.java:1205)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart0(GridQueryProcessor.java:910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:1068)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCaches$d40a1773$1(GridCacheProcessor.java:1860)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCaches$13(GridCacheProcessor.java:1745)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareStartCaches(GridCacheProcessor.java:1854)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareStartCaches(GridCacheProcessor.java:1744)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCachesOnLocalJoin(GridCacheProcessor.java:1690)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.initCachesOnLocalJoin(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1062)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:896)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3301)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3937)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
    ... 30 more
[10:39:03] Topology snapshot [ver=682, locNode=9397d621, servers=1, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=14, offheap=9.5GB, heap=8.2GB]
[10:39:03]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
[10:39:25,584][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#42%organization-service%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, consistentId=117403a3-0118-446e-a134-55d21c5342af, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.23.0.2], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /172.23.0.2:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1603777111439, loc=false, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1603777123055, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=680, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, consistentId=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.208.225, 192.168.0.101], sockAddrs=HashSet [DESKTOP-QG9I541.mshome.net/172.17.208.225:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, host.docker.internal/192.168.0.101:0], discPort=0, order=680, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1603777111299, loc=true, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=true], topVer=680, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@34d23ad2, nodeId8=9397d621, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1603777123048], nodeId=9397d621, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1603777110784, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3935)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3635)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3375)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3180)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3013)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2960)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2100)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2138)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.clientOnlyExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:952)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3301)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3937)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
    ... 15 more
[10:39:48,850][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#42%organization-service%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, consistentId=117403a3-0118-446e-a134-55d21c5342af, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.23.0.2], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /172.23.0.2:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1603777111439, loc=false, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1603777123055, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=680, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, consistentId=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.208.225, 192.168.0.101], sockAddrs=HashSet [DESKTOP-QG9I541.mshome.net/172.17.208.225:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, host.docker.internal/192.168.0.101:0], discPort=0, order=680, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1603777111299, loc=true, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=true], topVer=680, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@34d23ad2, nodeId8=9397d621, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1603777123048], nodeId=9397d621, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1603777110784, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3935)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3635)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3375)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3180)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3013)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2960)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2100)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2138)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.clientOnlyExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:952)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3301)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3937)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
    ... 15 more
[10:40:12,117][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#42%organization-service%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, consistentId=117403a3-0118-446e-a134-55d21c5342af, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.23.0.2], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /172.23.0.2:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1603777111439, loc=false, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1603777123055, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=680, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, consistentId=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.208.225, 192.168.0.101], sockAddrs=HashSet [DESKTOP-QG9I541.mshome.net/172.17.208.225:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, host.docker.internal/192.168.0.101:0], discPort=0, order=680, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1603777111299, loc=true, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=true], topVer=680, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@34d23ad2, nodeId8=9397d621, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1603777123048], nodeId=9397d621, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1603777110784, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3935)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3635)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3375)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3180)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3013)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2960)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2100)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2138)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.clientOnlyExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:952)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3301)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=c7b40322-bea4-49bf-ad1e-61fd2faa3116, addrs=[/172.23.0.2:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3937)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3781)
    ... 15 more
[10:40:12] Local node will try to reconnect to cluster with new id due to network problems [newId=fcc27049-fd1d-4f36-911a-9a548257ed3c, prevId=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, locNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, consistentId=9397d621-4fc8-435c-aa5d-49f07710dedf, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.208.225, 192.168.0.101], sockAddrs=HashSet [DESKTOP-QG9I541.mshome.net/172.17.208.225:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, host.docker.internal/192.168.0.101:0], discPort=0, order=680, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1603777111299, loc=true, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=true]]
[10:40:23,343][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-sock-writer-#2%organization-service%-#37%organization-service%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to send message: null
java.io.IOException: Failed to get acknowledge for message: TcpDiscoveryClientMetricsUpdateMessage [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=null, id=5d3a0986571-fcc27049-fd1d-4f36-911a-9a548257ed3c, verifierNodeId=null, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=true]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$SocketWriter.body(ClientImpl.java:1471)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
[10:40:24] Client node was reconnected after it was already considered failed by the server topology (this could happen after all servers restarted or due to a long network outage between the client and servers). All continuous queries and remote event listeners created by this client will be unsubscribed, consider listening to EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED event to restore them.
```

Comment: ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("SomeAddress:SomePort")); please show the actual configuration here

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added actual configuration please check now.

Comment: I think you missed one exclamation mark in your `LOGGER.info()` call